# How to create our own metadata in Dart?

Tags: annotations, dart, metadata

I want to create some own metadata for my dart codem, e.g. @table, @column, but I can't find any useful documents about it.

But I do found there are some special metadata (e.g. NgController) in angular.dart: https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/blob/master/demo/todo/web/todo.dart#L52

How to create my own metadata in Dart? Is there any documents?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Dart supports metadata which is used to attach user defined annotations to program structures.

Metadata consists of a series of annotations, each of which begin with the character @, followed a constant expression that starts with an identifier. It is a compile time error if the expression is not one of the following:

1. A reference to a compile-time constant variable.
2. A call to a constant constructor.

Metadata can appear before a library, part header, class, typedef, type parameter, constructor, factory, function, field, parameter, or variable declaration and before an import, export or part directive.

---

So, suggested by you constants such `@table`, `@column` are very limited by functionality because they cannot hold additional information (parameters).

```dart
@DataTable("sale_orders")
class SaleOrder {
  @DataColumn("sale_order_date")
  DateTime date;
}

@table
class Product {
  @column
  String name;
}

const DataColumn column = const DataColumn();

const DataTable table = const DataTable();

class DataTable {
  final String name;

  const DataTable([this.name]);
}

class DataColumn {
  final String name;

  const DataColumn([this.name]);
}
```

But in any case, you choose the option that best suits your needs.

Comment: The headline is misleading. The annotation support in Dart happens only via external packages like build_runner and/or code_gen. There is no native support for annotations in Dart.

Comment: `Dart supports metadata which is used to attach user defined annotations to program structures`. Source: Dart Programming Language Specification 5th edition draft Version 2.0.0-dev.  https://github.com/chalin/dart-spec-and-grammar/blob/master/doc/dartLangSpec.pdf. You incorrectly interpret the concept. Language has always supported metadata. Another thing is that there is a theory (language specification) and practice (compilers, third party tools etc).

Comment: I was talking about practice - that's the only thing I care about. If it works just in theory it's irrelevant (at least for me)

Comment: "If it works just in theory" also sounds ambiguous. Another thing how often it used in real practice? Angular compiler uses the metadata. Does this means that this is not a real practice? Or need some other more realistic examples? Eg. when metadata was used by Vasya Pupkin in their package(s)?

Comment: "Angular compiler" - thats the point. There is always some kind of extra-compiler or, in Darts-case, a builder necessary. In my opinion thats more a hack than a feature. Sure - this helps to keep the compiler lean but this also moves the responsibility to the package authors and brings different implementations for such a basic functionality.

Comment: You wrote: "The annotation support in Dart happens only via external packages...". Which kind of support you mean? As for me,  I can say: "They works very well even without any support of external tools because I can use them at the runtime when Dart script executed in virtual machine.". For me this means that they supported by the Dart VM. Dart VM is internal tool but not an extrenal package. So I can make conclusion that they are supported not only via external packages but also supported by the internal tools. Moreover, they are supported precisely by internal tools in the first place.

Comment: Answer is correct. Dart has very decent reflection support. Problem is that it's not supported in compiled targets like js or mobile because treeshaking eliminates metadata. So the way reflection is most often used in dart is to generate static code in build phase when application is loaded in dart JIT and thus metadata is accessible.

Answer (score 8):

- This is an interesting blog post about Dart annotations
  http://japhr.blogspot.co.at/2013/01/i-love-dart-annotations.html
- Here the meta data part of the Dart language specification
  https://www.dartlang.org/docs/spec/latest/dart-language-specification.html#h.d0rowtffuudf

> Metadata consists of a series of annotations, each of which begin with the character @, followed a constant expression that starts with an identifier.

So you can use a class with a const constructor as annotation.

- Dart Up and Running
  https://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/contents/ch02.html#ch02-metadata

Comment: I tried to go to the Dart Annotations link and it was dead for me.  Do you happen to have an updated Link to a list of default decorators / annotations in DartLang and PolymerDart ?

Comment: I was just going to go over this link to discuss the base ones: https://github.com/dart-lang/polymer-dart/wiki/properties

Comment: The second link is broken.