# dart api crossed out variables

Tags: api, sdk, dart

In most Dart documentation pages, some variables and functions are crossed out. like in https://api.dartlang.org/1.14.2/dart-js/dart-js-library.html

What does this signify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It signifies that the class, function, property etc. is [deprecated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deprecation)

In Dart, annotations are used to mark something as deprecated. Notice the documented annotation on [this class](https://api.dartlang.org/1.14.2/dart-js/JsNative-class.html).

Answer (score 3):

In Dart [metadata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553436/how-to-create-our-own-metadata-in-dart) can be added to classes, fields, library declaratoins, parameters, ... as annotation.

```
@Deprecated('some reason')
class SomeClass {
  String someField;
  int otherField;

  SomeClass({
      this.someField, 
      @Deprecated('don\'t use this anymore") this.otherField});
}
```

is such an annotation and some tools like the Dart analyzer and [dartdoc](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/dartdoc) use this information to produce warnings (Analyzer) or other visual cues that some API still exists but should be avoided because it's planned to be removed eventually.