# Howto access Dart annotations metadata

Tags: annotations, dart, metadata

Got most of the logic behind what is going on here : 
[How to create our own metadata in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553436/how-to-create-our-own-metadata-in-dart)

Apart from a thing. The annotation `@column` is put above the property `String name`, but I don't grab how this relation is obtained, where is the information with `String Person.name` located/accessed?

Dart-polymer 0.x uses this intensive. A property is marked for binding with `@property`.

https://github.com/dart-lang/polymer-dart/blob/master/lib/src/common/property.dart#L29

https://github.com/dart-lang/polymer-dart/wiki/properties

So it works, looking into the Dart-polymer source don't give me that much of a clue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, [`package:analyzer`](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/analyzer) is used. You'll end up writing a custom visitor for most functions that involve statically analyzing Dart code. If you look at the [Polymer transformer source](https://github.com/dart-lang/polymer-dart/blob/master/lib/transformer.dart), you'll see it uses [package:reflectable](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/reflectable) and [`package:web_components`](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/web_components), two transformers which use static analysis.

https://github.com/dart-lang/web-components/blob/master/lib/transformer.dart

https://github.com/dart-lang/reflectable/blob/master/reflectable/lib/transformer.dart

Comment: Thanks gave me a clue. Maybe dart-polymer could be a little misleading, I suspect some of the annotations also are used by js-polymer. Will look at `package:reflectable` instead.

Comment: The link to "Polymer transformer source" seems broken. :)

Comment: @rinukkusu Fixed. :)