# What does the @ ('at sign') sign mean in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, syntax, sdk

What does the @(at sign) mean in dart?

```
@immutable
@JsonSerializable(createToJson: false)
class ClassA  {

  @JsonKey(name: 'field_1')
  final int field1;
  @JsonKey(name: 'field_2')
  final String field2;

  const ClassA(this.field1, this.field2);

  factory ClassA.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$ClassAFromJson(json);
}
```

Comment: @ is used for annotations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@ sign means `Metadata annotation`

> Use metadata to give additional information about your code. A metadata annotation begins with the character @, followed by either a reference to a compile-time constant (such as deprecated) or a call to a constant constructor.

More on [dart.dev](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#metadata)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553436/how-to-create-our-own-metadata-in-dart